# Identity Server 4 changing my redirect uri on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, azure-web-app-service, identityserver4

I encountered an issue where the RedirectUris changes to raw URL instead of a registered domain.

For instance, I have an azure app running on `test.azurewebsites.net` and registered a domain for it on "test.com" so I set my RedirectUris for the client as `test.com/signin-oidc` but as soon as I log in on the identity server it tries to redirect to the raw URL `test.azurewebsites.net:443/signin-oidc`.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is to review these two GitHub issues:

- [IdentityServer/IdentityServer4#324](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/324)
- [IdentityServer/IdentityServer4#4631](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4631)